# Access and modify values within an array in a HashMap: Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two hashmaps which both have a string as a key and an array of strings as a value. I need to modify one of the values in one HashMap based on the values in the other.

So basically I have an HashMap called genericSlots and another called bookedSlots. If the bookedSlots HashMap values are also contained in the genericSlots values I would like those values to be removed from the genericSlots HashMap

I have tried doing this as shown in the code below but the values in the genericSlotsAsArray are not being removed.

Here is the code:

```
  checkForBookedSlots(date:string){

  let genericSlots = new Map<string,string[]>();
  let bookedSlots = new Map<string,string[]>();
  
  let bookedArray = ['09:00','11:00']
  let slotTimes = ["09:00", "09:30","10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30","13:00","13:30", "14:00","14:30","15:00","15:30","16:00","16:30"]
  
  bookedSlots.set("09/10/2021",bookedArray)
  genericSlots.set(date,slotTimes)
 
  let genericSlotsAsArray = Array.from(genericSlots.values());
  let bookedSlotsAsArray = Array.from(bookedSlots.values())
  
  for(let i=0;i< genericSlotsAsArray.length; i++){
      for(let j=0;j<bookedSlotsAsArray.length;j++){
          let mValue = bookedSlotsAsArray[j];
          if(mValue === genericSlotsAsArray[i]){
              const index = genericSlotsAsArray.indexOf(mValue, 0)
              genericSlotsAsArray.splice(index, 1)
          }

      }
  }
  console.log('Generic Slots -> ', genericSlotsAsArray)
  console.log('Booked Slots -> ',  bookedSlotsAsArray) }
```

Expected output:

```
Generic Slots - > ["09:30","10:00", "10:30","11:30", "12:00", "12:30","13:00","13:30","14:00","14:30","15:00","15:30","16:00","16:30"]

Booked Slots -> ["09:00","11:00"]
```

Actual Output:

```
Generic Slots - > ["09:00","09:30","10:00", "10:30","11:00","11:30", "12:00", "12:30","13:00","13:30","14:00","14:30","15:00","15:30","16:00","16:30"]

Booked Slots -> ["09:00","11:00"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
checkForBookedSlots(date: string) {
    let genericSlots = new Map<string, string[]>();
    let bookedSlots = new Map<string, string[]>();

    let bookedArray: string[] = ['09:00', '11:00'];
    let slotTimes: string[] = ['09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30'];
    let genericSlotsArray: string[] = slotTimes.filter(slot => !bookedArray.includes(slot));

    genericSlots.set(date, genericSlotsArray);
    bookedSlots.set(date, bookedArray);

    console.log('Generic Slots -> ', genericSlotsArray);
    console.log('Booked Slots -> ', bookedArray);
}
```